# Deploying some files in .gitignore to AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Knowing that `eb deploy` will deploy anything in your git repo, what is the best way to include files in that are included in `.gitignore`? I.e. config scripts with credentials etc.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 44):

The answer is creating an `.ebignore` file. Here is how it works:

If you have `my_keys.php` in your `.gitignore` because you don't want to commit it because of sensitive info, create an `.ebignore` file and only add files that you don't want to be distributed to your instances.

If you don't add `my_keys.php` to your `.ebignore`, it will compile it and distribute while `.gitignore` will keep it out of your remote repo.

This behavior is explained in AWS [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-ebignore):

> If .ebignore isn't present, but .gitignore is, the EB CLI ignores
>   files specified in .gitignore. If .ebignore is present, the EB CLI
>   doesn't read .gitignore.

Comment: Does this mean that if a file is not in the .ebignore it will be pushed to the elastic beanstalk instance even if it is in the .gitignore?

Comment: And I quote (from AWS), "If no .ebignore is present, but a .gitignore is, the EB CLI will ignore files specified in the .gitignore. If an .ebignore file is present, the EB CLI will not read the .gitignore." (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3-configuration.html#eb-cli3-ebignore)

Comment: @Ryan comment should be added to that response as is.